# Wait for jquery to load HTML, then remove item

Tags: javascript, jquery

With the code below:

```
function create_table() {
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "/api/data/",
        success: function(data){
            $('#table').load('http://127.0.0.1:8000/results');
            $('#go_back').remove();
        },
        error: function(error_data){
            console.log("errorrr")
            console.log(error_data)
        }
    })
}
document.getElementById("create_table").onclick = function() {
    create_table();
    return false;
}
```

I want to remove `#go_back` element after `#table` element is loaded. The problem is it doesn't get removed because the code doesn't wait for `#go_back` to appear.

How do I make the script wait before those `.load` and `.remove` methods?

Comment: Is there a .done method you can use on .load? Eg. .load('http...').done(function() { $('#go_back').remove(); });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you are having is that the `load` function is asynchronous, while the `remove` function you are calling is synchronous. The rough sequence of events is below.

- an AJAX request is performed
- the AJAX request returns success
- the success callback is called
- the `load` function makes a second asynchronous call to localhost to load the results into an element identified with ID `table`
- the 'load' function takes some time to complete
- in the meantime, the `remove` function is called
- the `remove` function inspects the DOM (Document Object Model) for an element matching ID `go_back`
- no matching element is found, because the `load` function has not yet returned
- the `load` function returns, and populates the inner HTML of the table element

The solution to your problem is to understand that any changes to be made to the contents of the table element must be made *after* the load function returns. This is accomplished by consulting the jQuery documentation [jQuery Load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to find out how to place a hook to the completion of the `load` function. This modification should accomplish what you want:

```js
$('#table').load('http://127.0.0.1:8000/results', function(){
     $('#go_back').remove();
});
```

In essence, pass a second parameter to the `load` function, which is another callback function. Inside this callback function, any code will be executed after the inner contents of the table element have been modified. Therefore the `go_back` element should be found and removed.

Answer (score 1):

There is a callback function in JQuery `load()` function that is triggered when the load completes. Thus, put that code inside the callback which will only execute after the `load()` operation is completed.

```
function create_table() {
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "/api/data/",
        success: function(data){
            $('#table').load('http://127.0.0.1:8000/results', function(){
              $('#go_back').remove();
            });
        },
        error: function(error_data){
            console.log("errorrr")
            console.log(error_data)
        }
    })
}
document.getElementById("create_table").onclick = function() {
    create_table();
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The .load function actually creates an Ajax call. You are using Ajax to get 'data', doing nothing with it and then using another Ajax call to get the result which I assume is some html.

You could get your Ajax function to populate the html based on the data rather than doing a second call.

I'm not sure if there is a .done func available from .load. But if there is you can remove the element in there.

Or, you can keep as is and change the .load function to a proper Ajax call and populate the table html in the success func, along with removing the element.

Comment: Thanks Steve. Would using the data from the first Ajax call (which is in JSON format) require stitching together HTML for the whole table as a string inside the parentheses of the `.load` method, or is there an easier way?

Comment: Yes, you'd have to output html.